# How to initialize a list of strings (List<string>) with many string values

Tags: c#, string, list

How is it possible to initialize (with a C# initializer) a list of strings? I have tried with the example below but it's not working.

```
List<string> optionList = new List<string>
{
    "AdditionalCardPersonAddressType","AutomaticRaiseCreditLimit","CardDeliveryTimeWeekDay"
}();
```

Comment: there's an example here for a multidimensional list in the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473358/c-sharp-pen-throws-outofmemoryexception

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 558, accepted):

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "element1", "element2", "element3" });
```

Comment: I don't think there's a good reason to initialize a string array here to create this object. Anyone who's looking, please use one of the other answers.

Comment: @Unsliced and @Padel have more correct answers imo. No need to pass in another `new` anything if you initialize with `{ }`

Comment: For C++ CLI it is like: `Collections::Generic::List<int>^ mylist = gcnew Collections::Generic::List<int>(gcnew array<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4})`

Comment: @Bobrot why? because allocating a `new String[]` is not efficient?

Comment: @DylanChensky I'd say as a general rule, doing anything unnecessary is inefficient. Granted, this one instance might not be a big deal, but imagine if your code is littered with items like this. It could make a big difference overall, especially when it comes to memory usage.

Answer (score 805):

Just remove `()` at the end.

```
List<string> optionList = new List<string>
            { "AdditionalCardPersonAdressType", /* rest of elements */ };
```

Comment: Are you referring to a specific version of .NET/C#? As far as I know this work from v3.5 and later. Don't know about 2.0 because I haven't used it for a while...

Comment: asp.net 2.0  btw I get the error after  { -> Error 7 A new expression requires () or [] after type

Comment: In 2.0 you must use it like this: `List<string> optionList = new List<string>() { "AdditionalCardPersonAdressType", /* rest of elements */ };`. Note the `()` here: `new List<string>()`.

Comment: It's a C# 3 language feature and has nothing to do with the version of the framework you're using. If you're still using Visual Studio 2005 you're not going to be able to use this feature.

Comment: this code has worked for me -: thumbs up!

Comment: Just a note that this is equivalent to initializing the collection with the default constructor and then calling Add for each element. Unfortunately it will not use the cardinality of the elements as capacity during construction. If you want to create the list with the right size from the start you still need to provide the capacity in the constructor.

Answer (score 190):

You haven't really asked a question, but the code should be

```
List<string> optionList = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", ..., "stringN"};
```

i.e. no trailing () after the list.

Comment: Error 7 A new expression requires () or [] after type

Comment: @blgnklc, because you're using C# 2 which doesn't support this feature.

Comment: var optionList = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", ..., "stringN"};

Answer (score 47):

```
var animals = new List<string> { "bird", "dog" };
List<string> animals= new List<string> { "bird", "dog" };
```

**Above two are the shortest ways, please see https://www.dotnetperls.com/list**

Comment: Is this preferred over the accepted answer? It seems simpler, with no need of an intermediate `string[]`

Comment: `var animals = new List<string> { "bird", "dog" };` was not suggested in the accepted answer. Further `(new string[]` is an addition command in the accepted answer which can be avoided.

Answer (score 18):

Your function is just fine but isn't working because you put the `()` after the last `}`. If you move the `()` to the top just next to `new List<string>()` the error stops.

Sample below:

```
List<string> optionList = new List<string>()
{
    "AdditionalCardPersonAdressType","AutomaticRaiseCreditLimit","CardDeliveryTimeWeekDay"
};
```

Comment: Did this work in 2010? MAYBE newer C# works different...

Answer (score 15):

If you are using  C# 9.0 and up you can use the new feature `target-typed new expressions` [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new)

Example:

```
List<string> stringList = new(){"item1","item2", "item3"} ;
```

Comment: C# 9 is from 2020. The question is from 2010...

Answer (score 9):

The right way to initialize along with declaration is :

```cs
List<string> optionList = new List<string>()
{
    "AdditionalCardPersonAdressType","AutomaticRaiseCreditLimit","CardDeliveryTimeWeekDay"
};
```

Comment: Did this work in 2010? MAYBE newer C# works different...

Answer (score 6):

This is how you initialize and also you can use List.Add() in case you want to make it more dynamic.

```
List<string> optionList = new List<string> {"AdditionalCardPersonAdressType"};
optionList.Add("AutomaticRaiseCreditLimit");
optionList.Add("CardDeliveryTimeWeekDay");
```

In this way, if you are taking values in from IO, you can add it to a dynamically allocated list.

Comment: In fact this is what happens "under the hood" of anyone is using the Collection initializer feature of C# 3.0 (I mean, finally all of those arguments end up in an Add command (when curious, try it in sharplab.io)

Answer (score 4):

One really cool feature is that list initializer works just fine with custom classes too: you have just to implement the **IEnumerable** interface and have a method called **Add**.

So for example if you have a custom class like this:

```
class MyCustomCollection : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    List<string> _items = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

this will work:

```
var myTestCollection = new MyCustomCollection()
{
    "item1",
    "item2"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Move round brackets like this:

```
var optionList = new List<string>(){"AdditionalCardPersonAdressType","AutomaticRaiseCreditLimit","CardDeliveryTimeWeekDay"};
```

Comment: Does not provide more information that those 2010 answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139118/how-to-initialize-a-list-of-strings-liststring-with-many-string-values/3139157#3139157,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139118/how-to-initialize-a-list-of-strings-liststring-with-many-string-values/54415837#54415837

Answer (score 2):

There is something else that you might be missing that hasn't been mentioned.  I think it might be the problem you are having as I suspect you already tried removing the trailing () and still got an error.

First, like others have mentioned here, in your example you do need to remove the trailing ();

But, also, note that List<> is in the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

So, you need to do one of the following two options:
[#1 below is probably the more preferred option]

(1)
Include the use of the namespace at the top of your code with:
using System.Collections.Generic;

or

(2)
Put the fully qualified path to List in your declaration.

System.Collections.Generic.List optList=new System.Collections.Generic.List
{    "AdditionalCardPersonAddressType","AutomaticRaiseCreditLimit","CardDeliveryTimeWeekDay"
};

Hope that helps.

The error message you receive when you implement List correctly but don't include the System.Collections.Generic namespace is misleading and not helpful:

"Compiler Error CS0308: The non-generic type List cannot be used with type arguments."

PS - It gives this unhelpful error because if you don't specify that you intend to use System.Collections.Generic.List the compiler assumes you are trying to use System.Windows.Documents.List.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from C# 12 it becomes much simpler using the [Collection Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions), for example:

```
List<string> optionList = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

**Note:** The feature is part of [.NET 8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0) released in Nov 2023.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the content tag C#, but if someone could use Java (the same search terms lead here):

```
List<String> mylist = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"element1", "element2", "element3" }.clone());
```

Answer (score -1):

In C# 12 you can do the following:

```
List<string> optionList = ["AdditionalCardPersonAddressType","AutomaticRaiseCreditLimit","CardDeliveryTimeWeekDay"];
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions)