# C# create list with multiple entries

Tags: c#

How can I create a list with a fixed set of entries.

Learning C# and doing an exercise to list all cards in a deck of cards(without jokers). Going to use two foreach loops to  print them out.

However I cannot get a default list of the cards(I am overloading the method). Looking at the  docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx and some examples http://www.dotnetperls.com/list and each element is added in individually.

```
// from dotnet perls
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    List<string> dogs = new List<string>(); // Example List

    dogs.Add("spaniel");         // Contains: spaniel
    dogs.Add("beagle");          // Contains: spaniel, beagle
    dogs.Insert(1, "dalmatian"); // Contains: spaniel, dalmatian, beagle

    foreach (string dog in dogs) // Display for verification
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dog);
    }
    }
}
```

I have tried both the Add and Insert methods but cannot create my lists.

```
// my code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Deck
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> deck = new List<string>();
        deck.Insert("Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King");
        List<string> colour = new List<string>();
        colour.Add("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs");
        foreach (string card in deck)
        {
            foreach(string suit in colour)
            {
                Console.Write(colour + " " + card);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code even compiling without errors?

Comment: Duplicate, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3139278/1726419

Comment: @yossico        thanks good link helpful. But not a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [List.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't take variable length parameters. You may need to use [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
List<string> deck = new List<string>();
deck.AddRange(new []{"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"});
List<string> colour = new List<string>();
colour.AddRange(new []{"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"});
```

Also note that I've converted the numerical parameters to string as the list is `List<string>`, otherwise it won't compile.