# How to assign a value to a List<string> inside a model

Tags: c#, .net

My model is like is

```
public class MovieListModel
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> FilePathList { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }
}
```

I Need to add assign value to the above model but the problem is adding the value to the list of string that is inside the model, List FilePathList.   I need something like this,

```
var obj = new MovieListModel()
 {
    FileName = fi.Name,
    FilePathList = , //  Need to add value here.
    Count = 1,
    Extension = fi.Extension,
    Size = Helper.FormatBytes(fi.Length),
    CreatedTime = fi.CreationTime,
    ModifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(item)
};
movieList.Add(obj);
```

Comment: `FilePathList  = new List<string>{"SomePath"}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a C# string list (List<string>) with many string values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139118/how-to-initialize-a-c-sharp-string-list-liststring-with-many-string-values)

Comment: if you want to add multiple `string`s, create a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = new MovieListModel()
            {
                FileName = fi.Name,
                FilePathList = new List<string> {
                    // Add value here
                },
                Count = 1,
                Extension = fi.Extension,
                Size = Helper.FormatBytes(fi.Length),
                CreatedTime = fi.CreationTime,
                ModifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(item)
            };
```

Answer (score 4):

That's one way :

```
var obj = new MovieListModel()
{
    FileName = fi.Name,
    FilePathList = new List<string>() { "Value" }, //  Need to add value here.
    Count = 1,
    Extension = fi.Extension,
    Size = Helper.FormatBytes(fi.Length),
    CreatedTime = fi.CreationTime,
    ModifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(item)
};
movieList.Add(obj);
```

There may be better way depending on what you're adding exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need

```
var obj = new MovieListModel()
                {
                    FileName = fi.Name,
                    FilePathList = new List<string>(){ obj, whatever...},
                    Count = 1,
                    Extension = fi.Extension,
                    Size = Helper.FormatBytes(fi.Length),
                    CreatedTime = fi.CreationTime,
                    ModifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(item)
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this. By creating a function you'll be able to pass any number of parameters to it, and get the desired output -

```
var obj = new MovieListModel()
            {
                FileName = fi.Name,
                FilePathList = MapMyStrings(fi.prop1, fi.prop2),
                Count = 1,
                Extension = fi.Extension,
                Size = Helper.FormatBytes(fi.Length),
                CreatedTime = fi.CreationTime,
                ModifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(item)
            };

List<string> MapMyStrings(params string[] objs){
     if(!objs.Length > 0) return null;
     return objs.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the above answers answer your question, but I just wanted to show you this in case that what you are looking to put in that list isn't a literal string (so in case you need to convert)

```
var obj = new MovieListModel()
{
    FileName = fi.Name,
    FilePathList = new List<string> { "Test", "Test1", fi.CreatedTime.ToString() /* use of .ToString() to convert other objects to string*/} /* and so on and so on */, 
    Count = 1,
    Extension = fi.Extension,
    Size = Helper.FormatBytes(fi.Length),
    CreatedTime = fi.CreationTime,
    ModifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(item)
};

movieList.Add(obj);
```

Hope this helps!