# Instantiating a List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, instance

If I want to instantiate a array the syntax is

```
int[] items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

and the shortcut is

```
int[] items = {1,2,3};
```

Now I want to do the same to a `List`.

**Question:**

why does this work:

```
List<int> items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToList();
```

but not this:

```
List<int> items = { 1, 2, 3 }; //invalid
```

or

```
List<int> items = { 1, 2, 3 }.ToList(); //invalid
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a C# string list (List<string>) with many string values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139118/how-to-initialize-a-c-sharp-string-list-liststring-with-many-string-values)

Comment: @ffguven I don't think it's a duplicate. The question is not _how_ to initialize a list, but _why_ those syntax examples do/don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax

```
int[] array = {1,2,3};
```

is special syntactic sugar for *array initialization*. `{1,2,3}` is not itself an array yet.

This line

```
List<int> list = new[] {1,2,3}.ToList();
```

works because the *expression* `new[] {1,2,3}` returns an `int[]`, which implements `IEnumerable<int>` and so you can call `ToList()` on it.

In the specs that's the difference between [12.6 Array initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx) and [7.5.10.2 Array creation expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691346(v=vs.71).aspx).

---

`List<T>` has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as argument to initialize the list's content with. So you can either call

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(new[]{1,2,3});
```

or use the *collection initializer* syntax sugar:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> {1,2,3};
```

which is converted by the compiler to something like this:

```
var tmp = new List<int>();
tmp.Add(1);
tmp.Add(2);
tmp.Add(3);
List<int> list = tmp;
```