# Initialize Nested List<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, list, initialization

Please refer the below code

```
List<ProductDM> productDMList = _orderRepo.GetProductList(32, 12);
  for (int i=0;i<productDMList.Count;i++)
        {
            productDMList[i].CabinetList[i].Min = productDMList[i].Min;
            productDMList[i].CabinetList[i].Max = productDMList[i].Max;
        }

public class ProductDM
  {
    public List<InventoryDM> CabinetList { get; set; }
    public double Min { get; set; }
    public double Max { get; set; }
 }
public class InventoryDM
 {
    public Double Min { get; set; }
    public Double Max { get; set; }
 }
```

The requirement is to loop through the `productDMList` and bind the returned `MIN` and `MAX` values inside the cabinet list. `ProductDM` fills with MIN and MAX amounts but when assigning those to CabinetList, it returns an error.

This is because the CabinetList is initially empty and it doesn't show the MIN MAX properties in it.

[image: Issue]

I am using the above code to assign data but returns

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

because of the CabinetList empty.

How to initialize the cabinet list here???

Comment: By *creating* a new list in the constructor and assigning it to `CabinetList`? *declaring* a member doesn´t implicitely *create an instance*. What should the list contain at start?

Comment: `ProductDM` needs a constructor that takes a `List<InventoryDM>` argument

Comment: In your `ProductDM` constructor, put `CabinetList = new List<InventoryDM>() `,

Comment: @HimBromBeere Initially MIN and MAX = 0

Comment: But what should the *list* contain at the start? I suppose - as min and max should be zero - the list should be an empty one. However you have to *provide* that initial value - even if it is empty (which is different from null)

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: When assigning your `Min` and `Max` use the `Add()` method of `List<>` to avoid *ArgumentOutOfRangeException*. `productDMList[i].CabinetList.Add(new InventoryDM {Min = productDMList[i].Min, Max = productDMList[i].Max});`

Comment: @croxy : Please add it as the answer. It worked. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Marco Forberg's answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50563727/5453249) initializing the `CabinetList` in the constructor prevents the

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

exception.

In addition to this, instead of assigning the `Min` and `Max` values via the index accessor:

```
productDMList[i].CabinetList[i].Min = productDMList[i].Min;
productDMList[i].CabinetList[i].Max = productDMList[i].Max;
```

You should use the `Add()` method of the `List<>` type:

```
productDMList[i].CabinetList.Add(new InventoryDM { Min = productDMList[i].Min, Max = productDMList[i].Max });
```

otherwise you will get an

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException

because you try to access an item on the list which doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements you could do something like this

```
public class ProductDM
{
  public List<InventoryDM> CabinetList { get; private set; }
  public double Min { get; set; }
  public double Max { get; set; }

  public ProductDM()
  {
    CabinetList = new List<InventoryDM>();
  }
}
```

or if you get your `CabinetList` data from an external source, e.g. database:

```
public class ProductDM
{
  private List<InventoryDM> _cabinetList = null;

  public double Min { get; set; }
  public double Max { get; set; }

  public List<InventoryDM> CabinetList
  { get
    {
      if(_cabinetList == null)
      {
        _cabinetList = ... // retrieve data from external source
      }
      return _cabinetList; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the emptiness of the CabinetList, instead the list of objects is null as you  can see in the debugger.
In order to initialize the list you can refer to the answers of this post:
[How to initialize a C# string list (List<string>) with many string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139118/how-to-initialize-a-c-sharp-string-list-liststring-with-many-string-values)

Note that you don't have a list of string but a list of `<InventoryBM>` objects, but the concept is analogous.