# How do i populate a list via argument when calling a function?

Tags: c#, function, arguments

I created this function that I want to populate my public dictionary (named "Assets") with keys corresponding with what I enter into the arguments when the function is called.  the issue is that I dont know how to populate the list when calling the function.  please help.  Here's my defined function:

```
public void addAssetDictKeysValues(List<string> keys)
    {
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            Assets[key] = true;
        }
    }
```

BUT HOW DO I CALL IT?

```
public void loginTest()       
    {
        loginBasic();
        addAssetDictKeysValues(??????????);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a C# string list (List<string>) with many string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139118/how-to-initialize-a-c-sharp-string-list-liststring-with-many-string-values)

Comment: addAssetDictKeysValues(new List<string>() {"a","b","c");

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a List object, which you can initialize like this

```
   List<string> yourList = new List<string> ();
    yourList.Add("test1");
    yourList.Add("test2");
```

Then, just pass it as an argument to your Method

```
addAssetDictKeysValues(yourList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the list coming from?  The front end?  The database?  What is the dictionary doing?

I would suggest renaming your method - the name you have is a little confusing.  Maybe AddAssets?

```
    {
        loginBasic();
        var yourList = new List<string>();
        yourList.CallAFunctionThatPopulatesTheList();
        addAssetDictKeysValues(yourList);
    }
```